# How to create template or placeholder in html and add them dynamically to the body?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a forum in html. As you have guessed I am new to web dev.

Let's say there is a template for messages posted by the users:

```
<div id="message">
    <h3>#name of the user</h3>
    <p>#message</p>
</div>
```

I wish to populate this template with the user's name and the message and then dynamically add it to the main body when the user posts it.

However as I told you I am very new to web development. I am not sure how to do this. All I need is your guideline and ideas. Maybe point me toward appropriate tutorial and references.

Comment: The best to do something dynamically on your html, is to use javascript.
You can see a very simple example of integration here : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: If you wish to create an actual forum this cannot be done with html alone. You'll need a database to store users posts, and an API to talk to the database. But as far as your question goes, you can use javascript to append markup to an element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Template Literals and just interpolate `name` and `msg` inside template.

```js
let template  = document.querySelector('div#message');

function createMessage(name,msg){
  return (
    `<div id="message">
    <h3>${name}</h3>
    <p>${msg}</p>
    </div>`
  
  )
}


let data = [{
  name:"name 1",
  message:"message 1",
},

{
  name:"name 2",
  message:"message 3",
},
{
  name:"name 3",
  message:"message 3",
},

]


let str = data.map(x => createMessage(x.name,x.message)).join('');

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",str)
```

Comment: `document.write` is [a **really** bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/6320039).... Why not `document.body.append`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use format unicorn to do this like stackExchange does, example:

Your Html:

```
    <div id="messageLoader">

    </div>

  <script type="text/template" id="templateMessage">
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <p>{message}</p>
    <br>
    <span><Strong>{sign}</strong><span>
  </script>
```

Your script:

```
String.prototype.formatUnicorn =  function () {
      "use strict";
      var str = this.toString();
      if (arguments.length) {
          var t = typeof arguments[0];
          var key;
          var args = ("string" === t || "number" === t) ?
              Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
              : arguments[0];

          for (key in args) {
              str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + key + "\\}", "gi"), args[key]);
          }
      }

      return str;
  };
  var jsonMessage = {title:"Custom Template With Form Unicorn",message:"Stack Overflow Rocks bae !!",sign:"Stan Chacon"};
  let myFirstUnicornTemplate = document.getElementById("templateMessage").text;
  var template = myFirstUnicornTemplate.formatUnicorn(jsonMessage);
  document.getElementById("messageLoader").innerHTML = template;
```

**EDIT:** fun fact you can use it here in stack overflow just copy and paste this on console :

```
"Hello {name}, welcome to StackOverflow {emoji}".formatUnicorn({name:"User",emoji:"=)"});
```

Or try the snippet:

```js
  String.prototype.formatUnicorn =  function () {
      "use strict";
      var str = this.toString();
      if (arguments.length) {
          var t = typeof arguments[0];
          var key;
          var args = ("string" === t || "number" === t) ?
              Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
              : arguments[0];

          for (key in args) {
              str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + key + "\\}", "gi"), args[key]);
          }
      }

      return str;
  };

var x = "Hello {name}, welcome to StackOverflow {emoji}".formatUnicorn({name:"User",emoji:"=)"});
console.log(x);
```

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using javascript you can manipulate the content of an html tag like this:

```
document.getElementById("yourhtmltagid").innerHTML = "#message";
```

you can learn the basics  on your own:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the notion of a forum in HTML (see comments on original post), [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) provide this functionality and have been [gaining support since the beginning of 2019](https://caniuse.com/?search=web%20components).

Web Components include `<slot>`s that can be used as placeholders in `<template>`s, custom elements that can define values for those slots, and shadow DOMs to display the result (see [*Using templates and slots*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots)).